# Spark Application. Why the "executor computing time" is too long?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time, task, executor

Spark Application

deploy mode:standalone

I want to know why the input data is same but the computing time is so different for a task between two different "WordCount" code.

For example:

1.The original "WordCount" code

```
object ScalaWordCount{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    if (args.length < 2){
      System.err.println(
        s"Usage: $ScalaWordCount <INPUT_HDFS> <OUTPUT_HDFS>"
      )
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ScalaWordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val io = new IOCommon(sc)
    val data = io.load[String](args(0))
    val counts = data.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                     .map(word => (word, 1))
                     .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    io.save(args(1), counts)
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

the task result:

[task duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w2Qs.png)

2.the other "WordCount" Code

```
object ScalaWordCount{
  def main(args: Array[String]){

    if (args.length < 2){
      System.err.println(
        s"Usage: $ScalaWordCount <INPUT_HDFS> <OUTPUT_HDFS>"
      )
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ScalaWordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val io = new IOCommon(sc)
    val data = io.load[String](args(0))
    val flatRdd = data.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    val mapRdd = flatRdd.map(word => {
      val pre = scala.util.Random.nextInt(10).toString
      val key = pre + "_" + word
      (key, 1)
    })
    val shuffleRdd = mapRdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)
    val shuffleMapRdd = shuffleRdd.map{ case (k, v) => (k.split("_")(1), v) }
    val counts = shuffleMapRdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)
    io.save(args(1), counts)
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

the task result:

[task duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uLW9.png)

So I want to know what will cause this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you have a look to the DAG and duration of each step of the process through Yarn? (I see you're using it from your screenshot, right?)

Comment: Not Yarn, but standalone. In the screenshot, the duration belongs to the task not stage.